# Cannot reach to members of an array with index

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to fill an array with data from Firebase. But after filling the array I can't call its' members from their index. I am filling the array by this function

```
func loadSounds(){
Firestore.firestore().collection("data").getDocuments{ (snapshot, error) in
    if error == nil{
        for document in snapshot!.documents{
            let name = document.data()["name"] as? String ?? "error"
            let sounds = document.data()["sounds"] as? [String : [String : Any]]
            
            var soundsArray = [dataSound]()
            if let sounds = sounds{
                for sound in sounds {
                    let soundName = sound.value["name"] as? String ?? "error"
                    let soundImage = sound.value["image"] as? String ?? "error"
                    soundsArray.append(dataSound(name: soundName , image: soundImage ))
                }
            }
            
            categoriesArray.append(Category(category: name , sounds: soundsArray))
        }
        print(categoriesArray[0].category)
       
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
} }
```

When I try to access it from View, It gives index out of bounds error.

```
struct ContentView: View {

init(){
    loadSounds()
}
   var body: some View {
      Text(categoriesArray[0].category)}}
```

If I try to access it via ForEach, it works, also when I try to print it from loadSounds function it works, but I need to access them from their index in View. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to make sure the array isn’t empty. The body will load before the firebase code is back with the data.

Comment: In other words, try this: `if categoriesArray.count > 0 {
     Text(categoriesArray[0].category)
 }`

Comment: @loremipsum thanks, but how can I fix this?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thank you so much, I didn't know that it updates in the view automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Never access items of an array by index in the rendering area of a SwiftUI View, in almost all cases the array is empty when the view is rendered the first time.

In your case use `.first` and handle the optional

```
var body: some View {
   Text(categoriesArray.first?.category ?? "No value")}} // or empty string
```